# how to show a widget when a condition is fulfilled flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this screen that should show me a listview, witch is between the second select and the red button, when the second select has unless 1 element inside, in the listview there is a listtile that load (it should do it) each one of the elements inside the second select.

this is the scaffold where i make question to call the widget:

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Center(child: Text("Tareas y Materiales")),
  ),
  body:Column(
    children: [
      _selectTareas(),
      _selectMateriales(),
      _materialesSeleccionados.isEmpty? Column() :  Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:20, bottom: 20),
        child: listaMateriales(),
      ),
      
      _buttonFinalizar(context, argumentos['des_id'])
    ],
  ) 
);
```

this is the listview that should show itself when I select the select's items:

```
listaMateriales(){
return Expanded(
  child: SizedBox(
    height: 200.0,
    child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _materialesSeleccionados.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final material1 = _materialesSeleccionados[index];
      
                  return _listItems (material1);
                }
            ),
  ),
);

}
```

this is the listTile inside the listView:

```
Widget _listItems(Material1.Material material) {
//_ZonasEncontradas = optListMenu;

//final List<Widget> optValueWidget = [];
print("Lo que hay en material es");
print (material);

return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:20),
  child: ListTile(
          title: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Text("")
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  // your TextField's Content
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
); 


}
```

Comment: I don't think I understand the question well, maybe you should make it simpler, some variables I don't understand what they are. However, to condition the appearance of a widget you can: 1) use "condition ? widget1 : widget2"; 2) if (condition) widget;
3) when one of these conditions changes in runtime, you can use "setState((){})" (using a StatefulWidget class) to update the whole class and thus update the conditions and widgets shown

Comment: when i set the element inside the _materialesSeleccionados, do i use the setState((){})?

Comment: I don't know, in the question you show where you use it but not where you get it